# Creating a desktop icon for Shiny App

Tags: r, shiny, desktop

I have a shiny app that opens in the browser when I provide the following code in the base R prompt:

```
shiny::runApp("C:/Myapp")
```

I use windows 7.  I am trying to create a desktop icon to avoid my client typing the above code every time he wants to use the app.  I have created a desktop icon and the set the path in "Target" as follows:

```
"C:\Program Files\R\R-3.2.2\bin\R.exe" -e "shiny::runApp("C:\Myapp")
```

and in the "start in" box I have included

```
"C:\Myapp"
```

The app is not opening.  I have tried changing the \ to / in C:/Myapp - doesn't work.  However, when I try the following:

```
"C:\Program Files\R\R-3.2.2\bin\R.exe" -e "shiny::runApp()
```

that is, without referring to my app folder, rhe R program runs, loads the code `shiny::runApp()` and prints the message

```
Listening on http://127.0.0.1:4354
```

Can someone help on how to resolve this? I have tried various combinations of the above.

Comment: Have you tried using Rscript.exe instead of R.exe?

Comment: @sebastian-c Yes, I did...same error

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, if your app folder is "C:\Documents\myApp", then your working directory should be "C:\Documents" (to insert in "start in" box).

Second, use ' ' for your inner quotes:
`"C:\Program Files\R\R-3.2.2\bin\R.exe" -e "shiny::runApp('C:/Myapp')"`

Third, consider launching your browser with your runApp command. Otherwise there might be nothing to see. (`shiny::runApp('C:/Myapp', launch.browser = TRUE)`)

Comment: it worked.  However there is a slight modification required.  Instead of using the forward slash \, I had to use the backslash / -  everywhere.  Many thanks.  My current code looks like this:  `"C:/Program Files/R/R-3.2.2/bib/R.exe" -e "shiny::runApp('C:/Myapp', launch.browser = TRUE)` in the "Target" box of the short cut and in the start in box I used `C:/`.  And it worked!!  Many thanks for your help and guidance.

Comment: Moreover save this script in a `bat` file then you can create a shortcut on desktop which points to that `bat` file and run it

Comment: @LeArNr Right, forward slashes everywhere inside the R command. Answer edited.

Answer (score 1):

The following code saved as a '.bat' file worked for me on Windows 10 as suggested by [RBloggers](https://www.r-bloggers.com/2017/12/launching-your-shiny-app-in-2-clicks/)

```
start "" "C:\Program Files\R\R-4.0.3\bin\Rscript.exe" C:\RShiny\MyShinyApp\app.R  /k
start "MyShinyApp" "http://127.0.0.1:4354/"
```