# Run R shiny app from shortcut (Windows 10)

Tags: r, browser, shiny

I would like to start a shiny app from a shortcut for the lay user, in a similar vein to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42421798/run-shiny-app-from-shortcut-windows-10) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35340432/creating-a-desktop-icon-for-shiny-app).

My problem is not getting the app to initiate but getting the browser to open. Upon clicking the shortcut, I get the command prompt and it loads the script and ends with the following: Listening on http://127.0.0.1:xxxx. However, no browser opens but the app is there if I manually navigate the browser to localhost:xxxx.

1st the script:

```
# packages and working directory
packs <- c("sp","raster","leaflet","shiny","shinydashboard","leaflet.extras","methods")
lapply(packs, require, character.only = TRUE)

setwd("C:/myfolder/test")

# some data to display
BNG <- "+proj=tmerc +lat_0=49 +lon_0=-2 +k=0.9996012717 +x_0=400000 +y_0=-100000 +ellps=airy +datum=OSGB36 +units=m +no_defs"

r <- raster(xmn=375000,xmx=380000,ymn=390000,ymx=395000,res=c(50,50),crs=BNG)
r[] <- sample(1:5,size=(50*50),replace = T)

#UI and Server
ui <- bootstrapPage(
  tags$style(type = "text/css", "html, body {width:100%;height:100%}"),
  leafletOutput("rasmap", width = "100%", height = "100%")
)

server <- function(input, output,session) {

  output$rasmap <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet() %>%
      addProviderTiles("CartoDB.DarkMatter", layerId = "rasmap",
                       options = providerTileOptions(minZoom = 6))%>%
      addRasterImage(r, opacity = 0.8)
  })

}

# tried with and without the below
options(browser = "C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe")

# I've tried the below in very many permutations
shinyApp(ui, server, options = list(launch.browser=T))
#shinyApp(ui, server)
#runApp(shinyApp(ui, server), launch.browser = TRUE)
```

Within the shortcut I have as follows:

Target: `"C:\Program Files\R\R-3.4.3\bin\R.exe" -e "shiny::runApp('C:/myfolder/test')"`

(I have tried `"shiny::runApp('C:/myfolder/test', launch.browser = TRUE)"` at the end of Target but causes it to immediately crash)

Start in: `C:/myfolder/test`

As I say, it works fine but will not launch the browser and requires manual input of the port number. Running Windows 10, R 3.4.3, works fine from vanilla R and RStudio.

Comment: I just tried the same in my win 10 and it works when you ` launch.browser` in the bat file.

Comment: ah, i'm not going for a bat file, just a shortcut. I think my work will block any unknown .exe or .bat. Maybe i should do this and ask for an exception.

Comment: I just verified with the shortcut and it worked. Don't keep any option for `shinyApp()` inside the code.

Comment: nope, as soon as i add ", launch.browser = TRUE" into the Target box, it fails immediately (no messages etc). Tried with shinyApp()

Comment: You must get some log inside the folder, did you check that?>

Comment: sadly nothing. leaving `shinyApp()` like that gives me an error for missing server

Comment: maybe i wasn't clear. leave it like this in the code `shinyApp(ui, server)`

Comment: yes, that is what i have it as. placing `, launch.browser = TRUE` in the Target box inside the shortcut is killing the job. otherwise it works fine and i have to manually type the port. oh well.